# Tier price table on product view page

Tags: php, template

I am trying to edit my view.phtml in my theme to build a tierprice table on my product view page so I am trying to first just list the price tiers but nothing is showing up.

I have found the following code in  : **/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/catalog/product/view/tierprices.phtml**

```
<?php
 $_product = $this->getProduct();
 $_tierPrices = $this->getTierPrices();
?>
<?php if (count($_tierPrices) > 0): ?>
 <ul class="tier-prices product-pricing">
 <?php foreach($_tierPrices as $_price): ?>
    <li><?php echo $this->__('Buy %1$s with %2$s discount each', $_price['price_qty'], '<strong class="benefit">'.($_price['price']*1).'%</strong>') ?></li>
<?php endforeach ?>
</ul>
<?php endif;?>
```

But when I paste it the view.phtml it shows nothing. But it is working at the top of the page next to the add to cart button ( default location ).

Can anyone point me in  right direction here or see what I am doing wrong.

Comment: make sure you have not catalog rules active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add following code in your view.phtml file

```
<?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml() ?>
```

Comment: Thankyou Jaydip. I have already done this though and it echo's a formatted lines of text like " Buy 6 for £2.65 each and save 8%  " but I actually need to to get all the values so I can construct a table

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by others you need to add `<?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml() ?>` 
This will use tierprices.phtml to create the output.
Then you must create `/app/design/frontend/[your-package]/[your-theme]/template/catalog/product/view/tierprices.phtml`

Keep the first few lines for data retrieval(such as `$_tierPrices = $this->getTierPrices();`) and then create the table as you wish. It will help to  `Zend_debug::dump($_tierPrices)` to see the data you have available.

Answer (score 0):

Please try overriding the following file:

- /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/tierprices.phtml

If you have a theme installed in your magento then look into:

- /app/design/frontend/***YOUR_PACKAGE***/***YOUR_THEME***/template/catalog/product/view/tierprices.phtml

Answer (score 0):

As per magento sytem has been show at `view.phtm`l using below code.

```
 <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml() ?>
```

You neeed to check this code exit on your view.phtml If not then need to add thos.